# MySQL doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb

Today I wanted to restart mariaDB because I couldn't connect to the database anymore. When I tried to restart it, I got these errors:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.7.3 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: failed (Result: resources) since Mon 2022-03-28 21:23:20 CEST; 18min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
      Tasks: 102 (limit: 36046)
     Memory: 613.7M
        CPU: 4h 54min 2.270s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
             └─127990 /usr/sbin/mariadbd

Mar 28 21:23:20 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Will not start SendSIGKILL=no service of type KillMode=control-group or mixed while processes exist
Mar 28 21:23:20 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: Device or resource busy
Mar 28 21:23:20 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Mar 28 21:23:20 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.7.3 database server.
Mar 28 21:41:36 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Found left-over process 127990 (mariadbd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Mar 28 21:41:36 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Mar 28 21:41:36 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Will not start SendSIGKILL=no service of type KillMode=control-group or mixed while processes exist
Mar 28 21:41:36 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: Device or resource busy
Mar 28 21:41:36 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Mar 28 21:41:36 vmd89408.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.7.3 database server.
```

From what I understand, the problem is that it wasn't properly shutdown. I already tried to kill the process by running `kill 127990` but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Is the mysql directory usually mounted? The message `device or resource busy` usually indicates that the filesystem is not available. So you might need to check all mount points and re-mount. If that doesn't work, a reboot might help.